# How to make right scrollable menu with buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I want to make scrollable menu (first view controller) with 4 buttons. Every button linked with specific view controller. But I want to make it specific: after app launching user must see only first three buttons on every iPhone version (4, 4.7, 5.5) and he needs to scroll down to see one more button. Should I use stack view with scrollview? Should I use UICollectionView (I found that's good for images but not for buttons)?

Thanks everybody for help!

[image]

Comment: @lurii Ushakov use table view.

Comment: CollectionView or TableView, just measure the height on startup and adjust cells height to your measured device height

Comment: Is it possible to set up table view so that only first three buttons will be visible on every iPhone version?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `UICollectionViewController` (or `UITableViewController`, either would work) you can layout your storyboard like this:

[image: Storyboard layout using uitableviecontroller]

Then in your `MyTableViewController` (again, this also works with a `UICollectionViewController`) you can implement the following method to set the cell size equal to a third of the window height:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // get the height for the current view
    let viewHeight = self.view.frame.height

    // since we want 3 rows to appear at a time, simply divide the viewHeight by 3
    return viewHeight / 3
}
```

Comment: Because the height is known and doesn't vary for every cell, you can also set the UITableiView.rowHeight and not implement this delegate method.